# Financial software that calculates total return?

Tags: osx, finance

Does anyone know of a service/software (osx) that can do the following?

- Create portfolio from various sources (stocks, mutual funds etc)
- Show the total return of the portfolio including capital gains (stocks went up in value) AND dividends paid out. From there calculating the total return and compounded annual growth rate.

I can't find anything at all that remotely comes close to this.